# Youtube API Activities return at maximum 256 activity instead of 297 activity

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I confusing in some issues cases about YouTube API  [Activities list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) 
the endpoint bring me at maximum 256 items for channels have more than 256 activities.

According this channel (`UC9zTuyWffK9ckEz1216noAw`) have a 297 videos (activities) while the Endpoint return 256 activities.

Example:

> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&channelId=UC9zTuyWffK9ckEz1216noAw&maxResults=50&_h=1&

1. First the totalResults change per page!
2. maximum items are return at maximum 256!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but in case if someone faces the same issue as the OP, I came up with a solution for this.

As OP mentioned, for some reason [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) has a max limit of 256 activities even thought it hasn't been mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities).

However since [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) allows us to use `publishedBefore` and `publishedAfter` as parameters, we can play around with that to get videos using `publishedBefore` set to `DateTime.Now()` converted into [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=50&publishedBefore=[DateTime.Now() in ISO 8601 format]&channelId=[Channel_Id]&key=[Your_API_Key]
```

This will return 50 videos published before the specified date with their details including `publishedAt`. Then for the next 50 activities you can get the last item from the returned list and pass the `publishedAt` value converted to [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) as the new `publishedBefore` parameter. And repeat this method until you get all the videos by checking if `nextPageToken` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list)

> nextPageToken  string
>   The token that can be used as the value of the pageToken parameter to retrieve the next page in the result set.

You will need to use the NextPage token to get the addiotnal results

```
"kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
 "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/CDAYwe0RayreWUk1bUL79fvoRUw\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 108,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
```

Example

> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.activities.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&channelId=UC9zTuyWffK9ckEz1216noAw&maxResults=50&pageToken=CDIQAA&_h=2&

Comment: Hi DalmTo, thanks for your answer :) 
that's  exactly what i'm do but if you note the API return at 256 items instead of 299 items, that is the problem

Comment: "totalResults": 108,<---- the channel you gave me has only 108 public.   The api can only return what it has access to